# identityserver 4- has no subid when auth from code

Tags: c#, identityserver4

I have code which auth against Identityserver 4 + entity framework using:
RequestClientCredentialsTokenAsync

i'm getting token but the after requests has no "sub" or "subid".

do i missing configuration in order to get "sub"?

Comment: Why are you expecting a 'sub' when you're using the client_credentials grant type? Since it is a client authentication outside the context of a user, a 'sub' is not needed.

Comment: Client_credentials is for [machine-to-machine communication](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/grant_types.html#machine-to-machine-communication) (no user interaction). The `sub` claim is only available in [flows where a user logs in](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/grant_types.html#interactive-clients).

Comment: so how can i make server logout for user turns inactive?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand your last comment. There is no user in the client credentials flow. So what do you mean by 'before user turns inactive'? And server logout? Perhaps you can explain what are you trying to accomplish.

Comment: I have mobile app which interact with my api, user login in the app and get a token. This token is good for 24 hours, but what if i want to force logout the user?               I want the to make specific user existing token invalid

Comment: You can't revoke a JWT access token because it is self-contained. Normally you can use short-lived access tokens and use a refresh token for requesting new access tokens when they expire. That way, the access token simply expires (still can't be revoked), but the refresh token can be revoked, which is almost the same as logging out the user.

Comment: Like Ruard said, the JWTs cannot be revoked but you may be interested in using reference token if you want more control over the lifetime of administered tokens: http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/reference_tokens.html